# Does cyclic field imply Galois?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field

I am thinking about the following statement, and I wonder if this is true: Every cyclic field is Galois. (we are in characteristics $0$).

I have started with a cubic case and tried to make use of the following proposition:

**Prop.** The splitting field of an irreducible polynomial $f(x)=x^3-px+q\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is cyclic iff the discriminant $\Delta(f)=4p^3-27q^2$ is a rational square.

Every cubic polynomial has one real root. So if we have a cubic polynomial whose discriminant is a rational square, then the splitting field $K$ (i.e Galois field) is cyclic and the real root generates the whole field. So all the remaining roots must also be real and belong to that field right? (As $K$ contains all the roots to the cubic polynomial)

Does it make any sense?

Does the statement hold in general for extensions of higher degrees ?

Many thanks

Comment: The splitting field of any polynomial over a perfect field is always Galois, since it is a normal, separable, finite extension by construction. I'm not sure what else you could mean by 'cyclic field' besides 'cyclic field extension'. Or perhaps you mean generated by one element, in which case the primitive element theorem says that any finite separable extension is primitive, just like you have now.

Comment: @IanColey: Thank you. Yes by cyclic field I mean the one that is generated by the primitive element.

Comment: @HeidiE that is usually called a simple extension. Cyclic extension means Galois with cyclic Galois group.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein: Thank you for this clarification.

Comment: @IanColey: the same goes to you. Thanks.

Comment: What Ian and Dustan say sounds right to me, too. But it also seems to me that you used the Proposition correctly. If the discriminant of an irreducible rational cubic is a square, then a single real root generates the splitting field. A generalization of the Proposition to higher degree $n>3$ polynomials states that if the discriminant is a square, then the Galois group is a subgroup of the alternating group $A_n$. It just happens that $A_3$ is cyclic, but for $n>3$ this is not the case.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thank you. I just wanted to make sure that I was allowed to make such statement. And since I am only interested in cyclic cubic real fields I think your comment exhaustively answers my question. I still have a simple extension (that is obviously cyclic) generated by one of the real roots of an irreducible cubic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$. Thank you again for the comment on the generalization.